# Definition of a functor for operads

Tags: category-theory

Let $\Sigma$ be a family of binary linear operations. By $\Sigma$-algebra we mean a linear space equipped with with a family of binary operation. Let $Var$ be the variety of $\Sigma$-algebras defined by a family $S$ of polylinear identities of any degree. We also consider an operad governing the variety $Var$ and also denote it by $Var$.

Why an algebra from this variety is a functor from $Var$ to $Vec$, the multi-category of linear spaces with polylinear maps?